# Protection in OS

Tags: operating-systems

According to the book " Operating Systems Concepts " , 9th edition, page 637, we have the following statement :

> Rather than associating the columns of the access matrix with the
> objects as access lists, we can associate each row with its domain. A
> capability list for a domain is a list of objects together with the
> operations allowed on those objects. An object is often represented by
> its physical name or address, called a capability. To execute
> operation M on object Oj , the process executes the operation M,
> specifying the capability (or pointer) for object Oj as a parameter.
> Simple possession of the capability means that access is allowed.

I am trying to understand how access is granted in such a scheme. This is described in the author's words:

> Simple possession of the capability means that access is allowed

I still can't understand it, so please if someone can explain it more. Thanks.